# ISO 4217 table for python

Tags: python

I need to obtain the currency name (in Spanish) from its code, like this:

```
divisas = {
    36: "Dólar australiano",
    124: "Dólar canadiense",
    208: "Corona Danesa",
    392: "Yen japonés",
    554: "Dólar neozelandés",
    578: "Corona noruega",
    752: "Corona sueca",
    756: "Franco suizo",
    826: "Libra esterlina",
    840: "Dólar USA",
    978: "Euro",
}
```

The full list is *huge*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#Active_codes

Is there some kind of library that allows me to do this easily? Yes, the Spanish name is necessary.

Comment: The Babel library (which I'm a maintainer of) has currency names in practically all languages. http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/

Comment: I see a function to retrieve the name from the text code (eg "USD"), but not from the numerical code (eg 840).